# Apps in Software Center won't download

Tags: software-center

I am trying to download TeamViewer and Skype via Software Center. They start downloading and show 100% on the progress bar, but never get actually downloaded or shown as such. I've tried rebooting and internet speeds are fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download skype and teamviewer (.deb file) by using official web sites.
Skype   https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/
Teamviwer https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/

and then open files using software center and install.